# Probability theory - Roulette, profit at the end of the day - SOLVED

Tags: probability, statistics, martingales, expected-value

SOLVED: See comment by henry. Thanks!

- 511 Dollar is the budget and the man tries a very known strategy. 
  Betting 1$ on red {with a probability of 18/37} and if he loses he doubles it. And if red comes on, stop playing. So he works against green and black {19/37}.

Say X is the profit at the end of the day, then what is the "entity" and the Probability mass function?

I am not sure what "entity" really means in english but this is my answer, it may become clearer:

E = {-511, -255, -127, -63, -31, -15, -7, -3, -1,1} 
The reason I have this is because he can never make more profit than 1$.

Because, for example, if he wins the first one, he leaves. If he loses the first one and wins the second, he doubled and won just a 1$ in the end. If he loses, he continues to double, til he reaches 511 Dollar because that is his budget.

And the pmf:

X->   -551 | -277 | -127  etc.

P(X) ->   {19/37} ^9 | {19/37}^8 | {19/37}^7 etc.

etc. because you'd need to lose 9 times in a row to lose your whole budget. 8 times in a row to lose -277 etc.

My question here is how do you calculate the probability of winning 1$, because there are multiple ways of doing so:
1. Win the first game
2. Lose the first, win the second. 
etc. 
9. Lose the first 8, win the ninth

I've tried this way:
18/37 + {19/37} * {18/37}  + {19/37}² *{18/37} .. but I really don't think this is the right way. Ive tried addition and multiplication but I think there is some wrong thinking here.

For the Expected value I would do it this way: -511*{19\over 37}^9 - 255*{19\over 37} etc. But my problem would be the P(X) of 1$ so to speak.

It would be nice if you can tell me the wrong doing here and maybe give me a tip on how to continue. I know the question is long but I think its not too difficult.

Comment: If you are looking at the final state, I would have though this was $\{+1,-511\}$ or perhaps $\{512,0\}$ depending on how you are measuring.  Let's assume the former.  The end state $-511$ has the probability you calculated while the end state $+1$ has a probability of $1$ minus the probability of $-511$

Comment: I don't understand the problem analysis complexity. This game has only two ending states. You win a 1 or lose 511. Losing requires a loss in each of 9 successive bets so it has a probability of (17/37)^9. Winning is just 1-(17/37)^9 which is .9991 to 4 places. Is there something I'm missing?